# Sql Select rows with a column1 value appearing with more than one column2 value

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I have a `SQL` table named `table_name` as follows:

```
+------------+------------+-----+---------------+
| login_name | session_id | ip  | creation_date |
+------------+------------+-----+---------------+
| name1      | sid1       | ip1 | date1         |
| name1      | sid1       | ip2 | date2         |
| name1      | sid1       | ip2 | date5         |
| name2      | sid2       | ip1 | date3         |
| name2      | sid2       | ip1 | date4         |
+------------+------------+-----+---------------+
```

I want an `sql` code (Postgres please) to select the rows where the `session_id` is used by more than one `ip`. For the example above, the result should be

```
+------------+------------+-----+---------------+
| login_name | session_id | ip  | creation_date |
+------------+------------+-----+---------------+
| name1      | sid1       | ip1 | date1         |
| name1      | sid1       | ip2 | date2         |
+------------+------------+-----+---------------+
```

I have this code that works, but I'm rather new and I believe it can be done better (more clear, better performance)

```
    SELECT table_name.login_name, table_name.session_id, table_name.ip, table_name_grouped.event_date AS creation_date 
    FROM table_name
    INNER JOIN
    (
        -- session_id - ip pairs
        SELECT table_name.session_id, table_name.ip, min(table_name.creation_date) AS event_date
        FROM table_name
        GROUP BY table_name.session_id, table_name.ip
    ) table_name_grouped
    ON table_name.creation_date = table_name_grouped.event_date AND 
        table_name.session_id = table_name_grouped.session_id AND
        table_name.ip = table_name_grouped.ip
    WHERE table_name.session_id IN (
        -- get session_ids that used in multiple ips
        SELECT table_name_grouped.session_id
        FROM 
        (
            -- session_id - ip pairs
            SELECT table_name.session_id, table_name.ip, min(table_name.creation_date) AS event_date
            FROM table_name
            GROUP BY table_name.session_id, table_name.ip
        ) table_name_grouped
        GROUP BY table_name_grouped.session_id
        HAVING count(table_name_grouped.session_id) > 1
    );
```

Note the following code repetition in the code above:

```
    SELECT table_name.session_id, table_name.ip, min(table_name.creation_date) AS creation_date 
            FROM table_name
            GROUP BY table_name.session_id, table_name.ip
```

So the question is:

1. Can the solution above be improved, how?
2. Do you see any potential problem, for example performance?

---

Update

I updated the example to show I only want one row per column1-column2 value pairs. (thanks for the amazing lighting-fast answers).

Answer (score 3):

```
select * from table_name
where session_id in
(
    select session_id
    from table_name
    group by session_id
    having count(distinct ip) > 1
)
```

The inner select groups by the `session_id` and takes only those having more than one unique `ip`. The outer selects get the complete records for those `session_id`s.

Another possibility would be joining the inner select with the outer instead of using `IN()`.

To only get the pairs with the smallest date use

```
select t.* 
from table_name t
join
(
    select session_id, ip, min(creation_date) dt
    from table_name
    group by session_id, ip
) t2 on t.session_id = t2.session_id and t.ip = t2.ip and t.creation_date = t2.dt
where t.session_id in
(
    select session_id
    from table_name
    group by session_id
    having count(distinct ip) > 1
)
```

Comment: Thanks @juerguen. I just updated the question as I would like only one row (the smallest date) with the `session_id` - `ip` pair.

Comment: So does your answer improved my solution? I see one select less, but do both solutions perform different (the sql engine does query optimization)? Any performance concern?

Comment: They perform slightly different. You can test it yourself. But Giorgos solution is probably faster.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name n
WHERE EXISTS ( -- another one exists
   SELECT *
   FROM table_name x
   WHERE x.session_id = n.session_id -- with the same session_id
     AND x.ip <> n.ip                -- but a different ip
   );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of window functions:

```
SELECT login_name, session_id, ip, creation_date
FROM (
  SELECT login_name, session_id, ip, creation_date,
         MAX(ip) OVER (PARTITION BY session_id) AS maxIP,
         MIN(ip) OVER (PARTITION BY session_id) AS minIP,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY session_id, ip 
                            ORDER BY creation_date) AS rn
  FROM table_name ) t
WHERE maxIP <> minIP AND rn = 1
```

`MAX` and `MIN` are used to detect `session_id` slices having more than one `ip` values (unfortunately a window version of `COUNT(DISTINCT ip)` is not available in Postgresql.

`ROW_NUMBER` is used to select the row having the minimum `creation_date` per `ip` per `session_id`.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/23df8/3)

Comment: Thanks @Giorgos. Does your solution improve my code? assuming I could use it in Postgres). It is not clear to me due to MIN MAX and three PARTITIONs.

Comment: Window functions generally perform very well, there is only a single table pass in my query, no joins. But you can test it yourself and compare execution times, logical reads etc.